# How come this question is A TEST for quality post review

Tags: discussion, review

EDIT
After rereading the question I should say most what I wrote here is wrong, so see comments.
/EDIT

So, there is this question

[Is this code instantiating or extending an abstract class without creating a new class?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17540386/how-to-instantiate-or-extend-an-abstract-class-without-writing-a-new-class)

which clearly shows that OP has completely no idea what abstract class is (and I do, despite never programming in Java)

How this is considered a quality question? (it clearly shows no understanding of matter, 30sec with google would answer it for him)
How it ended up as a test?
Is there a way to remove it from being a test - in my opinion it's too controversial.

(it's my first post in meta so forgive me if I broke some rules)

Comment: Its not asking what an anstract class **is**, its why can you instantiate an abstract class. That its an anonymous class isnt 101

Comment: Picking a question that was closed and then re-opened by a mod does seem an interesting choice for a question that's supposed to be obviously good.

Comment: It's a specific programming question with 16 upvotes, many comments supporting it, and a couple of good, highly upvoted answers. I see little controversial about it. The people who voted to close this did so in error, in my opinion.

Comment: Ok, after one more reading I think the question is just poorly formatted and this makes it highly misleading. Maybe I'll try to improve it.

Comment: So I made an edit, please take a look at it http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17540386/revisions

Answer (score 1):

From the question (in question?):

> First I checked the Javadoc, and WindowAdapter is an abstract class.
>   So how can he be instantiating it?

So the user clearly understands what an abstract class is. And he is also notes that he is new to Java.

I wouldn't say it is a **high** quality question, but I don't see what your issue is with it either.

Comment: See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191108/how-come-this-question-is-a-test-for-quality-post-review#comment594340_191108